# adding the value of a Radiobutton and checkbox to javascript database

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, windows-phone-7, cordova

We have on the first page (index.html) two radio buttons and we need to store the value to a database in javascript (see attached database in word).
And on the settings page we have also two radio buttons, the selection made on the index.html page must be put into the settings.html page and read out the selected choice, if the user changes the option (in our case english or dutch) we need to store this value in the database again, this is only possible on the settings.html page (the user can return to the index.html page, this is a one-time-setup page)

This is the script of the two radio buttons that are both on the index.html and the settings.html:

```
<input type="radio" name="set-language" id="dutch" checked />
<label for="dutch" class="flag-nl">Dutch<span></span></label>
<input type="radio" name="set-language" id="english" />
<label for="english" class="flag-uk">English<span></span></label>
```

And we have the same question to take the value of a checkbox, here is the code that we have on our settings page, also for the checkboxes we need to add the value inside the database and also be able to show them again if the user returns to the settings page (so he sees what choices he has made before). This code is only available on the settings.html page.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cards-nsyearcard" id="cards-nsyearcard" />
<label for="cards-nsyearcard">NS jaar/trajectkaart</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="cards-thepassbusiness" id="cards-thepassbusiness" />
<label for="cards-thepassbusiness">ThePass Business</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="cards-thepassweekend" id="cards-thepassweekend" />
<label for="cards-thepassweekend">ThePass Weekend</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="cards-thalys" id="cards-thalys" />
<label for="cards-thalys">Thalys TheCard</label>
```

We are a little stuck at the moment with this part so you help is very much appriciated. :-)

and here is the database that we are using:

```
   //database storge
  function dbBtn(){
    db.transaction(populateDB,errorCB, successCB);
     $.mobile.changePage("settings_succesfull.html" );
     }
function  loadSettings(){
         db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
  }
function bdClick(){
  $.mobile.changePage("settings.html");
     db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
 }
 function queryDB(tx) {
     tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM user', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}
function querySuccess(tx, results) {
      len = results.rows.length;
        if (len > 0) {
            for (var i=0;i<len;i++) {
                 $("#user-         name").val(results.rows.item(i).userName);
                 $("#user-insertion").val(results.rows.item(i).userInsertion);
                 $("#user-lastname").val(results.rows.item(i).userLastname);
                 $("#user-email").val(results.rows.item(i).userEmail);
            }
        } 
}

function transaction_error(tx, error) {
alert("Database Error: " + error);
}
function tableDB(tx) {
// tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user');
        var sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user ( "+
        "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        "userName VARCHAR(50), " +
        "userInsertion VARCHAR(50), " +
        "userLastname VARCHAR(50), " +
        "userEmail VARCHAR(50), " + 
        "age VARCHAR(20))";
         tx.executeSql(sql);
         }
function populateDB(tx) {
        var setName = $("#user-name");
    var setInsertion = $("#user-insertion");
    var setLastName = $("#user-lastname");
    var setEmail = $("#user-email");
    var setGender = $("input:checked");
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USER (userName, userInsertion, userLastname,     userEmail,age) VALUES ("' + setName.val() + '", "' + setInsertion.val() + '", "' +     setLastName.val() + '", "' + setEmail.val() + '","' + setGender.val() + '")');
 }
function errorCB(tx, err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: "+err);
}
function successCB() {
 //   alert("success! ");
}
```

Comment: Just an FYI, I don't think windows phone 7 supports HTML5 databases so watch out if you're planning on deploying this phonegap app to windows phone.

Comment: thanks will do some research on this point